# Left join no devuelve todas las filas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT 
    usuarios.id as 'ID',
    CONCAT(nom,' ',ap1,' ',ap2) AS 'NOMBRE',
    correo AS 'CORREO',
    count(historias.id) AS 'HISTORIAS PUBLICADAS',
    fn AS 'FECHA DE NACIMIENTO', 
    usuarios.status AS'STATUS' 
FROM usuarios 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN historias on historias.id_usuario = usuarios.id
```

De las tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ap1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ap2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `contra` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `fn` date NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id`, `nom`, `ap1`, `ap2`, `correo`, `contra`, `fn`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'Olga', 'Medina', 'Battle', 'quam@magnaseddui.edu', 'a7e2e2aa50566163cdc43249029de470', '2020-01-15', '1'),
(2, 'Dylan', 'Hopper', 'Williamson', 'lobortis.tellus.justo@accumsaninterdum.co.uk', 'a7e2e2aa50566163cdc43249029de470', '2021-02-21', '1'),
(3, 'Destiny', 'Lott', 'Cline', 'felis.adipiscing@eu.net', 'a7e2e2aa50566163cdc43249029de470', '2020-12-25', '1'),
(4, 'Flavia', 'Greer', 'Barry', 'amet.massa.Quisque@Nuncquis.co.uk', 'a7e2e2aa50566163cdc43249029de470', '2021-06-06', '1'),
(5, 'Ina', 'Wells', 'Pena', 'Etiam.ligula.tortor@massalobortis.org', 'a7e2e2aa50566163cdc43249029de470', '2020-07-06', '1');


CREATE TABLE `historias` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `publico` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `anonimo` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `contenido` longtext NOT NULL,
  `fecha_creacion` date NOT NULL,
  `ult_mod` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `historias`
--

INSERT INTO `historias` (`id`, `id_usuario`, `publico`, `anonimo`, `contenido`, `fecha_creacion`, `ult_mod`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 3, '1', '1', 'historia', '2020-11-02', '2020-11-02 11:14:47', '1'),
(9, 3, '1', '1', 'historia', '2020-11-02', '2020-11-02 11:24:50', '1'),
(10, 3, '1', '1', 'historia', '2020-11-02', '2020-11-02 11:34:05', '1');
```

Pero la consulta me devuelve solo las filas que tienen >=1 historias publicadas y quiero que me devuelva todas con el valor NULL o 0.

detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.detalles.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `LEFT OUTER JOIN`? Prueba a cambiarlo por `LEFT JOIN` simplemente.

Comment: Tampoco funciona.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar qué te arroja la consulta y qué esperas obtener? No logro entender en concreto cuál es el problema.

Comment: Solo me devuelve el usuario con el id 3, que es el que tiene datos en la tabla historias, quiero que me devuelva todas las filas, aunque no tengan historia

Comment: Yo creo que lo que te falta es el agrupamiento de tus columnas,  agrega esto  `group by usuarios.id , CONCAT(nom,' ',ap1,' ',ap2), correo, fn, usuarios.status`

Comment: Vaya, es cierto, muchas gracias estive como una hora atorado con este error.